# increase size of icon/image on long press like fb messenger

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, emoji

Wanted to make something like Facebook Messenger application emojis.
When we long press emoji then it's size increase continuously up to some limit.

I want to develop same for image/icon in web page.

I want to make like that using css and JavaScript (if required).

[Here](http://littlebigdetails.com/post/127557387249/facebook-messenger-press-and-hold-the-like)'s the sample like what I want to perform.

If anyone have idea on it then please let me suggest some hint.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set interval `onmousedown` event, and clear that interval `onmouseup`. To be more specific you can just create interval of 100ms for example and increase size of your element every 100ms after `mousedown` event and clear that interval after `mouseup` event.

```
var interval; 
var img = $('#img');

img.mousedown(function(){
interval = setInterval(function(){
    var image = document.getElementById('img');
    image.width += 5;
    image.height += 5;
   }, 100);

    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
   clearInterval(interval);
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you give me some small example for this ?

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ Check my update

Comment: shows me interval is not defined on console.

Comment: just define interval in global scope, like so

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zdLmx2ag/ check this fiddle

Comment: here's a https://jsfiddle.net/qhz6amnr/ can you check why it's behaving weird ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7gmgmL0L/ ok this is working fiddle try it out including image resize